# escape problem with beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, escaping, confluence

I am using the beautifulsoup4 in python in order to update the table on the confluence page when I use the soup.append(str) function, the `< >` were escaped and became `&lt; &gt;` so that i can not update the table correctly. Could someone give me tips? Or maybe some better solution for update the table on the confluence page, thanks in advance. :)

what i expect:

```
<tr>"string"</tr>
```

what the result:

```
&lt;tr &gt;"string"&lt; tr&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you append string to other tag. The solution is to create [`new_tag()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) or whole new soup.

For example:

```
txt = '''
<div>To this tag I append other tag</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
soup.find('div').append( BeautifulSoup('<tr>string</tr>', 'html.parser') )

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div>
 To this tag I append other tag
 <tr>
  string
 </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and solved my problem :)